# French regional setting Number format issue

Tags: .net

I have a .Net application in which i have entered some values say 0.21 when my regional settings as in English but when i change it to French settings the number gets converted to 0,21 and when i read and convert it to double i get this value as 21 instead of 0.21

Any help would be appreciated

Code
dblWork = Convert.ToDouble(txtInput.Text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're converting the number to and from a string. In this case, the [invariant culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c5zdc6a%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) should be used so that the current culture does not affect the output formatting and parsing of the number.

```
using System.Globalization;

// ...

var number = 0.23f;
var str = number.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var number2 = float.Parse(str, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```